# How to upload File from Angular 7 to Django - get error 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: django, angular, file-upload, http-post, angular-httpclient

I tried now in so many different ways, I can not get a file uploaded with Angular 7 to the Django Backend - shouldn't be so difficult?!

My **.html**:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="file">Choose File</label>
  <input type="file"
         id="file"
         (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

**uploader.component.ts**

```
  fileToUpload: File = null;

  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    this.uploadFileToActivity();
  }

  uploadFileToActivity() {
    this.uploaderService.post(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(data => {
      // do something, if upload success
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

my **uploader.service.ts** that also shows the upload progress

```
public post( fileToUpload: File): Observable<number>{
    const url = '/api/upload/';

    var subject = new Subject<number>()
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, fileToUpload, {
        reportProgress: true,
    });

    this.httpClient.request(req).subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
            const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
            subject.next(percentDone);
          } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            subject.complete();
          }
    });
    return subject.asObservable();
  }
```

And in the Django backend:

**views.py**:

```
def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

and **urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'api/upload/', views.post, name='post'),
]
```

When I ran this I get

```
zone.js:2969 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/ 403 (Forbidden)
```

Do I need to include an authorization token? If yes: how?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: After the useful input from Martin Urbanec I inspected the file upload request in the Browser. Here the result:

[image: inspection of upload request from angular to django in browser]

Someone any idea what I need to change in my code above to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

`Content-Type` header must be `multipart/form-data` to transfer any files. I recommend you to check if this header is sent to your Django backend.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't set the content type, unfortunately this didnt solve my problem. Still I get error 403. How can I check if the header is correctly sent? Breakpoints in the backend are never reached.

Comment: You can open developer console in your browser. For instance in Google Chrome it's F12. In this developer console, find Network tab, open it and try to upload a file. You can then open the request and examine it, including its headers.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for this idea. Maybe you can help me figuring out what I need to change to make this work? I added my findings above in the question